# Does Apache Beam support iterative algorithms, just like Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

Apache Flink supports iterative transformations: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/batch/iterations.html.

Is this also supported using Apache Beam or can we achieve the same thing using Beam concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have posted this question on the [user mailing list of Apache Beam](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/20fc9a223a106a2538adab48d7d43de30a96398267453ebcb9ca2c43@%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E).

There is an open ticket for this ([BEAM-106](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-106)), but it is not yet started.

There are two solutions:

- Unroll the loop yourself, which of course limits the number of iterations. Be careful with the number of transformations you create. This can be limited by the runner.
- Create multiple pipelines and store the intermediate data. This allows for easier debugging, but comes with overhead of storing and loading the data.